# Can't double.Parse string

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have a problem with parsing a string to a double. I have a `StreamWriter` reading lines from a text file. The text file has the following lines:

```
17-09-2012: (100,98)
17-09-2012: (50,57)
```

Now, I want to use the values from inside the parantheses, add them together and display them in a textbox. So far I have the following:

```
int counter = 0;
double res = 0;
string line;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("d:\\test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string par = Regex.Match(line, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Value;
    double par2 = double.Parse(par);
    res += par2;

    counter++;
}
file.Close();
textBox1.Text = res.ToString();
```

However, apparently the input string is not in a correct format, which I find rather odd, since the regex should remove everything but the numbers inside the parantheses. I have even checked for this by writing the string to the textbox without first adding them together, and it showed `"100,9850,57"`. So truly, I do not understand, why it cannot convert the string to a double.

I hope you can tell me, what I am doing wrong.

Comment: +1 for adding an SSCCE and showing what you've tried.

Comment: I'm not sure if your language supports commas for your Doubles

Comment: I don't think this is the case, since I have made a calculator which can in fact deal with numbers containing commas. Back then I made nothing special to allow for this.

Comment: Have you output the contents of the strings? Are you sure it's just numbers and commas?

Comment: @Brian Warshaw
Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your "par" variable is containing a string that looks like: "(100,98)" which is why it's failing to parse.

Comment: I don't understand how it can. When I output "par" as pure text it contains no parantheses.

Comment: I found out something else in my code was removing the parantheses. After changing the Rexex to ouput only the numbers, it still won't parse it.

Answer (score 1):

change your regex to `(?<=\()(([^)]*))(?=\))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with - based on `InvariantCulture`

```
 var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
 double result = double.Parse(par , culture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force double.Parse to use a culture that uses `,` as a decimal separator, like this:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
double d = double.Parse(par, culture);
```

That's a good idea anyway, if you want your program to work also on computers with different regional settings.

Comment: When I type in "CurrentCulture" it says it cannot find the type or namespace. Do I have to type "using.something;" to use this?

Comment: `using System.Globalization;` but I made a mistake (it's a CultureInfo, not CurrentCulture...)

Comment: Even now, it won't accept the input. Apparently it is not the comma.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't accept the input"? Does it throw an exception? If yes, what does it say?

Comment: It says "Input string was not in a correct format." and points to the line:

"double par2 = double.Parse(par);"

Answer (score 0):

Setting your regex to `(?<=\()(([^)]*))(?=\))` and using this helper should solve your problems:

```
        public static double ParseDouble(string input)
        {
            // unify string (no spaces, only . )
            string output = input.Trim().Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", ".");

            // split it on points
            string[] split = output.Split('.');

            if (split.Count() > 1)
            {
                // take all parts except last
                output = String.Join("", split.Take(split.Count() - 1).ToArray());

                // combine token parts with last part
                output = String.Format("{0}.{1}", output, split.Last());
            }

            // parse double invariant
            double d = Double.Parse(output, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            return d;
        }
```

Comment: How to implement this in my code? Can I put it in the "while" parantheses?

Comment: No, you have to put it inside the same class or on a separate .cs file within a new class like "Helpers" or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I made it work, by making a try, catch:

```
string par = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<=\()(([^)]*))(?=\))").Value;
                try
                {
                    double par2 = double.Parse(par);
                    res += par2;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
```

Thanks, everyone for your help.